# .Net AES encrypt mismatch after decrypt on Java

Tags: java, .net, utf-8, character-encoding, aes

I have to send the AES encrypted json as content to web server. But after decryption, the content has extra trash symbols appeared at the beggining of the line.

My test method creates the object that is serialized and being send:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SendModeChangeWorksAsExpected()
{
    var snpashot2Send = new ModeChangedReport
    {
        
        ControlWorkMode = ModeEnumeration.Stopped,
        //Controls
        ControlDate = DateTime.Now,
        IsSent = false,
        SentTime = null,
        ReportType = ReportType.ModeChanged,

        Line = new Line
        {
            AgencyId = "a799eb4f-86da-4af1-a221-9ed8b741b5ce"
        }
    };

    //Создаём шифрованное значение
    var encryptedString = _agencyReportEncriptingTranslator.ConvertModeChange2CypheredString(snpashot2Send);
    //Отправляем в Агентство и получаем результат
    var value = _agencyClient.SendModeChangeReport(encryptedString);
}
```

Here are the serialization and encrypt methods:

```
public string ConvertModeChange2CypheredString(ModeChangedReport report)
{
    if (report == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(report));

    //obj to json
    var json = new ModeChangedReportJson
    {
        LineId = report.Line.AgencyId,
        Mode = CreateModeFromIktToUzbekistan(report.ControlWorkMode),
        ActionDate = ConvertDateToAgencyString(report.ControlDate)
    };

    //Serialization
    var retString = _agencyJsonSerializer.SerializeReport2Json(json);

    //Шифруем сериализованный json
    var cypheredValue = _encryptionService.EncryptString(retString);
    return cypheredValue;
}
```

Encrypt method:

```
public string EncryptString(string plaintext)
{
    var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
    var cypheredTextBytes = Encrypt(plainTextBytes);
    var converted2Base64Value = Convert.ToBase64String(cypheredTextBytes);
    return converted2Base64Value;
}

private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytes)
{
    #region Args Validation

    if (bytes == null || bytes.Length < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid bytes to encrypt");
    }

    if (_key == null || _key.Length < 1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid encryption key");
    }


    #endregion

    byte[] encrypted;

    try
    {
        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Key = _key;
            aes.IV = _iv;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, _iv);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
                encrypted = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }

    return encrypted;
}
```

Http client send method:

```
public bool SendModeChangeReport(string cypheredValue)
{
    var token = GetAccessToken();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AuthorizationToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DEVICE_ID", _agencyAppSettings.DeviceId);

        var content2Post = new StringContent(cypheredValue, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using (var response = client.PostAsync(_agencyAppSettings.SendModeChangedReportUrl, content2Post).Result)
        {
            string tokenResponse = null;
            try
            {
                tokenResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _eventLogManager.LogError("При попытке отправить отчёт о смене режима, произошла ошибка: "
                    + $"Код: {response.StatusCode}. Контент: {tokenResponse}. Ошибка: {ex.Message}.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After decryption on receiving server, the string grows with extra trash characters at the beginning, like G���h R��EQ�Z {"lineid":"a799eb4f-86da-4af1-a221-9ed8b741b5ce"...

The decrypt method of the server (Java):

[image]

I think that the problem is the padding difference: PKCS7 on my side, and PKCS5 on server.

How can I solve this problem with the extra chars appear on server side?

Comment: Those aren't trash characters, it's what you get if you try to read ASCII text using the wrong codepage. The very fact you get *any* readable text means decryption succeeded.

Comment: Post your code as *text*, not images. Images can't be copied, googled and tested. The Java code is suspicious, as it tries to create a `String` out of the bytes returned by `doFinal` without specifying an encoding. I'm not going to type that line just to highlight it though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This image is all I have from the Developer of the Server

Comment: The Java code is using the [String(byte[]) constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,int)). According to the docs: `Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset.`. That's obviously not UTF8. Use `public String​(byte[] bytes,Charset charset)` or `String​(byte[] bytes,String charsetName)` instead

Comment: `all I have from the Developer of the Server` the bug is in their code. They have to either change their code to use the correct character set or change the machine's default character set to UTF8

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't trash characters, they're the [Unicode Replacement Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) returned when bytes are decoded into text using the wrong character set.

The very fact you got readable text means decrypting succeeded. It's decoding the bytes into text that failed.

The bug is in the Java code. It's using the [String(byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,int)) which, according to the docs:

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset.

That's obviously not UTF8. The [String​(byte[] bytes,Charset charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,java.nio.charset.Charset)) or [String​(byte[] bytes,String charsetName)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,java.lang.String)) constructors should be used instead, passing the correct character set, eg :

```
byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(....);
return new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The hacky alternative is to change the remote server's default character set to UTF8.